# Unable to upload healthvault certificate to windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, healthvault

I am going crazy on the following problem: I am developing a webapplication (asp.net) for the Microsoft HealthVault. During development everything works fine.

However, I need to publish the development version (PPE) to Azure. Downloaded the publish file and 30 seconds later, my project was published on Azure. So far so good. However, a certificate must be uploaded (a .pfx) file.  Although I do have the certificate as a .pfx file, I cannot upload it, because Azure requires a password in the certificate. But this certificate is auto created by the Health Vault Application Manager, and does NOT have a password.

How can I fit the certificate with a password? How am a supposed to proceed? Any thoughts, I am kind of stuck right now. As far as I can see, Microsoft itself hasn't foreseen this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you have to do is add a password to your pfx file. You can use [certutil](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx) or [openssl](https://www.openssl.org/). I don't think either allows you to do this step directly, but both allow you to import/export the cert and private key and add a password in the process. For example [Howto: Change password on pfx certificate using openssl](http://www.1st-setup.nl/wordpress/?p=105) (first Google hit):

> Export you current certificate to a passwordless pem type:
>
> ```
> [user@hostname]>openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pfx -out tmpmycert.pem -nodes
> Enter Import Password:
> MAC verified OK
> ```
>
> Convert the passwordless pem to a new pfx file with password:
>
> ```
> [user@hostname]openssl pkcs12 -export -out mycert2.pfx -in tmpmycert.pem
> Enter Export Password:
> Verifying - Enter Export Password:
> ```
>
> Remove the temporary file:
>
> ```
> [user@hostname]rm tmpmycert.pem
> ```

(The example uses Linux openssl, but you can use the Windows version too, same syntax).

Comment: Thank you man! You totally saved me. For future reference: I downloaded OpenSSl for windows here: https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html and then i entered the two statements Remus stated above. that worked without problems. After this the .pfx has a password and i succeeded in installing it in Azure.